# How do I alternate colors in Flat List (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Trying to alternate colors in `React Natives` `Flatlist`. I believe I need rowID or something similar to do it. This is what I've got so far:

```
let colors = ['#123456', '#654321', '#fdecba', '#abcdef'];


<View >
    <FlatList style={{backgroundColor: colors[this.index % colors.length]}}

      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.listStyle}>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />
  </View>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `renderItem` callback argument has a property `index` that allows you to access the row index for the current row:

```
<View >
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors[index % colors.length] }}>
        <Text style={styles.listStyle}>{item.title}, {item.releaseYear}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But how do I actually use it: `<FlatList style={{backgroundColor: ???}` should it be `this.color` ?

Comment: @johanjohansson you don't give the backroundColor to FlatList, you'll give it to each row separately inside the `renderItem` callback. I updated the code sample to reflect this

Comment: If you are using react-native-element's ListItem then use this :                 
```<ListItem
        containerStyle = {{ backgroundColor: index % 2 == 0  ? "#f2f2f2" : "#FFFFFF" }}```
/>

Comment: Is there any way to do this for SectionLists?